# Postfix ports configuration

Tags: email, firewall, port, postfix

I'm using postfix to send emails. So, and correct me if I'm wrong, I'm using port 25 TCP inbound for entering emails, and port 25 TCP outbound for sending emails. Is it possible to alter the 25 outbound port value used by postfix to 60000 for example?

Comment: Sorry, I read this question as "How can I change my configuration in order to connect to the remote server on a port different than 25?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *listening* on port 25 for incoming emails.

You are *connecting* to a *remote server* on port 25 for outgoing emails.

The port you connect *from* is randomly generated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the transport table using the command postmap. With postmap you can modify the way postfix interacts with the other servers for the outgoing message.

See http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html in order to understand how you can accomplish this for a particular user/recipient/domain as almost every public SMTP server is listening to 25 and 587 TCP only!

Comment: I think what you need is the page examples. You have to create a text file and call postmap to process that file with the transport directives. Or as you can see from the first part of the webpage call postmap with the desired string